# Using X-XSS-Protection with specific domains?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, http-headers, xss, frontend

I'm planning on adding `X-XSS-Protection: 0` header in order to allow requests between `mydomian.com` and `mystaticdomain.com`.  Can this header be used with a specific domain, as in `X-Frame-Option`/`Allow-From`?

https://www.keycdn.com/blog/x-xss-protection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this header does not allow this.

If you want a secure solution, you should implement [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) which will allow you to specify which domains can access content normally protected by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) by use of a header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: mystaticdomain.com
```